# Row count broken up by a focal value

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the following `DataFrame` in `Spark` using `Scala`:

```
val df = List(
    ("random", 0),
    ("words", 1),
    ("in", 1),
    ("a", 1),
    ("column", 1),
    ("are", 0),
    ("what", 0),
    ("have", 1),
    ("been", 1),
    ("placed", 0),
    ("here", 1),
    ("now", 1)
    ).toDF(Seq("words", "numbers"): _*)

df.show()
+------+-------+
| words|numbers|
+------+-------+
|random|      0|
| words|      1|
|    in|      1|
|     a|      1|
|column|      1|
|   are|      0|
|  what|      0|
|  have|      1|
|  been|      1|
|placed|      0|
|  here|      1|
|   now|      1|
+------+-------+
```

I'd like to add a column that contains the count of rows which is started over at every `0` in the `numbers` column. It would look like this:

```
+------+-------+-----+
| words|numbers|count|
+------+-------+-----+
|random|      0|    5|
| words|      1|    5|
|    in|      1|    5|
|     a|      1|    5|
|column|      1|    5|
|   are|      0|    1|
|  what|      0|    3|
|  have|      1|    3|
|  been|      1|    3|
|placed|      0|    3|
|  here|      1|    3|
|   now|      1|    3|
+------+-------+-----+
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method using `selectExpr` with SQL window functions `sum` and `count`; `sum` of `1-numbers` generates the group id which increases by 1 when a zero is encountered, then `count` the number of rows by this group id:

**This might be inefficient since you don't have any partition column.**

```
df.selectExpr(
    "words", "numbers", 
    "count(*) over(partition by sum(1-numbers) over (order by monotonically_increasing_id())) as count"
).show

+------+-------+-----+
| words|numbers|count|
+------+-------+-----+
|random|      0|    5|
| words|      1|    5|
|    in|      1|    5|
|     a|      1|    5|
|column|      1|    5|
|   are|      0|    1|
|  what|      0|    3|
|  have|      1|    3|
|  been|      1|    3|
|placed|      0|    3|
|  here|      1|    3|
|   now|      1|    3|
+------+-------+-----+
```